# how to report Chai asserts in mocha-reporter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

i'm writing a mocha reporter, and i wish get info about all the asserts which has been done during the test.

i use Chai frameworks for asserts in my unit-tests.

however, i don't succeed in getting information on the success asserts.
i only succeed to get info on the failed asserts by registering to fail event:
       **runner.on("fail", (test, err) => this.onFailedTest(test, err));**

is There a way on get info on  the passed asserts in a mocha reporter?

Thanks,
Shubert Yuval.

Comment: I think Mocha is totally oblivious when it comes to which assertions a test contains, it only deals with tests (and whether they fail or pass).

Comment: is there a way to extend chai that it will reports the asserts to a custom reporter?

Comment: Chai has an option to create [plugins](http://chaijs.com/api/plugins/) for it, but the next question will be: how do you make it report to your reporter. Besides that, I'm not sure if the plugin route will allow you to hook all assertions.